# Problems in copying files on Android 6

Tags: android-pc, file-sharing

I use a *Huawei p9* with **Android 6**. I notice a big problem. When I connect the phone with a *Lubuntu* pc trying to share files, I get e.g. that for copying 7 folders - each containing several small files for constructing html's pages - from pc to phone they are required about 10 minutes, when the total size of the folders is just 30MB!

On the other hand, when I perform the same action e.g. using instead 3 multimedia files of the same total size (i.e. 30MB), the amount of time is just 1 second (as indeed I expect).

Can someone explain why do I verify such an exaggerate discrepancy in time between the two mentioned cases? I think it may depend on the Android system (potentially by the emui p9 redesign -- otherwise every Android 6 device should have this problem!).

I  finally notice that with a more dated device mounting Android 4.2, I don't encounter that inconvenience.

Comment: @beeshyams mtp seems to be the default usb configuration. Nothing is changed because nothing is changed.

Comment: Seems like another victim of MTP. Unless you're willing to resort to pulling out files with ADB, I don't really see a solution...

Comment: @AndyYan do you mean that this is a known matter? Is it an Android bug? Using adb shell the process will be fast?

Comment: I've always observed such slowness with large numbers of files, and specifically it takes absurdly long to *prepare* for copying as well. Using `adb pull` to pull things out will skip that preparation which is good enough for me, but still, the storage chips on phones aren't exactly good at R/W small files (continuous transfer performance is much better), so performance will take a hit.

Comment: @AndyYan that's true. I had noticed it me too; sequential data are better than little fragmented files. But with Android 4.2 the discrepancy was acceptable, with Android 6 it is not -- i.e. it is impossible to reasonably complete the task. I really don't understand why such an involution, I thought more recent versions of android were better than the older. Now I will install adb on linux, then I'll try the same tasks -- if I've rightly understood, with this tool it is the linux system that menages files operations.

Comment: @AndyYan Compliments! That was the real solution (could be the right answer). With `push` it copy recursively, and it do it in a reasonable time (just copied a tree of about 1.2GB). Just a little "inconvenience": void folders are not considered. Is there a way to force their copy using "adb" syntax, or is it needed a little script?

Comment: Glad you find it useful, and on top of that you don't find it troublesome to use `adb` :) The empty folder behavior seems to be by design, and I got no solution for that by searching around. I'd probably post this whole stuff as an answer later.

Comment: But I am astonished for this behaviour: so many processors, something like Star Trek saga, and a basic operation like data pasting appears as a microbe if compared to a PC from the 80's :)